# Probleming echoing out members with profile links PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a members page to my website which lists every member's name as a link to their profile.

I am having some issues with the code below:

```
<?php
include 'include/connect.php';

$query = mysql_query("Select distinct fname, id from users");

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
     {
   $raw_link = $row["id"];
   $link = "<a href='profile.php?id='.$raw_link   >";
     echo $link.$row["fname"].'</a><br/>';
     }
?>
```

The users are being echoed out fine, however when I click the user's name it does not go to their appropriate profile, only "profile.php?id=1"

My question is: How can I list all the names of the users in my database as a link to their profile?

Comment: **using mysql is evil**, use mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$link = "<a href='profile.php?id='.$raw_link   >";
```

should be

```
$link = "<a href='profile.php?id=".$raw_link."'>";
```

You are closing your href attribute after `id=`. Also as commentator says, you should use MySQLi or PDO instead of MySQL.

Comment: Seemed to fix the issue, was on this problem for hours, now I feel like such a noob lol. Also - when using multiple quotations, should I always nest single quotes within double quotes and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$raw_link."\">";
```